# Comparing Multiple Objects In Single List

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This may be a duplicate but I have been looking for a couple of hours now and I keep coming up short. So here goes:

```
I don't have any code yet. I got p*ssed and deleted most of it! :P
```

I am writing a simple program, that will draw a hand of five cards from a deck of cards. Now, that I can do. However, I am making a button that will keep drawing from a fresh deck until it hits a pair.

Now the issue is the comparison of the five drawn cards. I am drawing them from a list

```
List<Card> TheDeck
```

and adding them to another list

```
List<Card> TheHand
```

The card class is pretty simple and only contains the first letter of the suit and a number.

```
public string suit;
public int number;
public Card(string suit, int number)
{
    this.suit = suit;
    this.number = number;
}
```

Now to draw a pair, I have to compare the numbers of the five drawn cards, to see if any of them match. The last way I did that, was by doing a GIANT if statement,

```
if (TheHand[0].number == TheHand[1].number || 
TheHand[0].number == TheHand[2].number || TheHand[0].number == TheHand[3].number || 
TheHand[0].number == TheHand[4].number /* .. and so on and so on .. */)
```

This I could do, but it just seems so excessive.
So there you have my question. What is the easier way to do this comparison of all the cards? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use LINQ's `GroupBy` to group the cards by their number, then see how many cards are in each group. I'd also suggest using an enum instead of a string for the suit, and using properties instead of fields.

Comment: Few questions: Do you have more than one card deck? if not, I would go with IComparable on your Card object. if you want to know more, I make you an answer for that.

Comment: @Aldert - I have a single deck of cards, that I reshuffle and redraw from, if it fails to draw a pair on the first attempt.

Comment: Big picture: .NET collections are smart about using `Equals`, `CompareTo`, `IEquatable`, & `IComparable`; and is not confused by a mix of inheritance, overriding, or implementing an interface. See [MSDN for `List` methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) like `Contains`, `Find`, `BinarySearch`, `Sort`, etc.  Take time to read about `IEquatable` & `IComparable` in MSDN. You don't have to understand all of it to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make your Card class to inherit from IEqutable, and using Equals method, define how you decide if two cards are pairs, and then use Linq.GroupBy as Selman is suggesting, but this time without specifying any conditions for groupBy. 
`input.GroupBy(c => c).Where(g => g.Count() > 1)`
The code is below, together with some test methods:

```
     public class Card : IEquatable<Card>
        {
            public string suit;
            public int number;

            public Card(string suit, int number)
            {
                this.suit = suit;
                this.number = number;
            }

            public bool Equals(Card other)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return Equals(number, other.number);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return number.GetHashCode();
            }

        }

        public class FindCardPairs
        {
            public static List<IGrouping<Card, Card>> FindAllPairs(List<Card> input)
            {
                List<IGrouping<Card,Card>> allPairs =  input.GroupBy(c => c).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();
                return allPairs;
            }
        }

[TestMethod]
        public void Card_Test_Equality()
        {
            var card1 = new Card(string.Empty, 2);
            var card2 = new Card("card2", 2);

            Assert.IsTrue(card1.Equals(card2));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_FindAllPairs()
        {
            var cards = new List<Card>
            {
                new Card(string.Empty, 2),
                new Card("card2", 2)
            };

            List<IGrouping<Card, Card>> actual = FindCardPairs.FindAllPairs(cards);
            Assert.IsTrue(actual.Any());
            Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Count());

        }
```

Comment: Recommended: Override `Object.Equals` when implementing `IEquatable` to ensure that both evaluate for equality the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the cards by number and check if there is any group that has more than one card:

```
TheHand.GroupBy(c => c.number).Any(g => g.Count() > 1)
```

To select the cards that match you can use `Where`:

```
TheHand.GroupBy(c => c.number).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the game you are creating, you can rate your cards independant. For now, the cards get compared by Number, see details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

The CardComparer can be used to sort the cards, I have sorted first on suit and then number, depending on the game you might decide to change this, remember when comparing cards, you always compare the 2 so you rules of comparing are nicely in the Compare method contained.

when adding items to the hand, you can use the following:

```
int index = TheHand.BinarySearch(newCard);
if (index>-1) //now a card with same number is found and you can take action
else
TheHand.Add(newCard);
```

Here the class code:

```
public class Card : IComparable<Card>
        {
            public Card(string suit, int number)
            {
                this.Suit = suit;
                this.Number = number;
            }

            public string Suit { get; }
            public int Number { get; }

            public int CompareTo(Card other)
            {
                return Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
            }
        }
```

Extra so you understand the concept better: For sorting use: `TheHand.Sort(new CardComparer());`

```
        public class CardComparer : IComparer<Card>
        {
            public int Compare(Card x, Card y)
            {
                int compResult = x.Suit.CompareTo(y.Suit);
                if (compResult == 0)
                {
                    compResult = x.Number.CompareTo(y.Number);
                }
                return compResult;
            }
        }
```

Note: when the queen of spades is the strongest, you can add this logic to the comparer. E.g. You can make a play comparer which compares the cards on the table.